# Google maps showing a visitor’s location by grabbing their IP address 

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to replicate the following exemple :

http://www.leigeber.com/2008/04/map-your-users-using-the-google-maps-api-and-php/

How to integrate this PHP source code with the following Java script (replacing lat/lgt with $latitude/$longitude above ??? Looks easy but I'm a bit lost in mixing PHP and Javascript together ! ;-(

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function initialize() {
      var map;
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));

        var zoomlevel = 9;
        var lat= 50.62829913465776;
        var lgt= 4.650295972824097;
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(lat, lgt), zoomlevel);

        // add a marker
        map.openInfoWindow(map.getCenter(), document.createTextNode ("Center of the map at (lat - lgt)= ("+lat+" - "+lgt+") ! "));

        // Large Map Default UI   
        map.setUIToDefault();

        // Map type
        map.setMapType(G_PHYSICAL_MAP);     
      }
    }
    </script>

<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">       
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px"></div> 
</body>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Hub

ps: is this the best way to do it ? is it good to use hostip.info or should I use another one ??

Comment: It doesn't look like you've even made an attempt to integrate the blog's code.  Nor is there any PHP above.  You should make an effort to get started before asking for help.

Comment: I did but had the message "max one link for new users" and so could not post my question. so I decided to shorten the post to be able to post it. Sorry about that. Hubert

Comment: Here's my test-page by the way : 
http://www.disy.be/gmap.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be fairly easy. Once you've fetched the $latitude and $longitude according to the linked example, you can use PHP to echo those values out to your Javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function initialize() {
  var map;
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));

    var zoomlevel = 9;
    var lat= <?php echo $latitude ?>;
    var lgt= <?php echo $longitude ?>;
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(lat, lgt), zoomlevel);
    .........
    ...............
</script>
```

That should get you going for the script mixing part. Remember, you've to use PHP to fetch the lat/long **BEFORE** you attempt to output the values to your JS.

In response to your queries, here's the general flow of code (say, in the file index.php):

```
<?php
// Code from the blog
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
.....
.......
$latitude = $res[2];
$longitude = $res[3];
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function initialize() {
          var map;
          if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));

            var zoomlevel = 9;
            var lat= <?php echo $latitude ?>;
            var lgt= <?php echo $longitude ?>;
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(lat, lgt), zoomlevel);
            .........
            ...............
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
    ......
    </body>
</html>
```

See if this helps you :)

Cheers,
m^e

Comment: Thanks a lot. referring to your advice to "use PHP to fetch the lat/long BEFORE you attempt to output the values to your JS." ... 

that's exactly my problem in fact... How do you do this in fact ? (sorry for this really beginner question ...)

the function initialize() is called on "body onload" (I'm following Google advice on this):

<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()"> 

so that the PHP script runs after the JS, no ?

I've tried and here's the result : http://www.disy.be/gmap4.php

Comment: Resolved: I moved the function initialize()
outside of the <head> </head> (I can do that I guess? Is that fine programing ?)
so that I can call first the PHP script, then function initialize() when doing <body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">

Here it is : http://www.disy.be/gmap5.php
Thanks for your help.

Hub

Comment: Yes of course. You can have the initialize() function anywhere within the HTML BODY tag too. Won't affect the functionality in any way. I'm attaching some more code stubs to my reply, which shows the general flow of code and allows you to leave the init function in the HEAD.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. This is perfect. Any way I can vote you up to thank you for this complete answer? (I have to wait for 15 reputation I saw)?

Comment: No problem at all :) Glad to be of help. Have you managed to get a working example up? I visited gmap5.php, but couldn't see any maps... but then again, my IP wasn't in the hostip.info database - I listed it just now. So quite likely, my IP didn't fetch any lat/long to generate the map properly.

Comment: Yup! Working now... once my IP was included in their DB. At least now I can see the country flag when I visit gmap5.php. However, the map is still missing and upon viewing your source, I see empty values for the lat / long. Have you included that second block of script (mentioned in the blog) that utilizes Google Maps API to fetch latitude-longitude from the City / Country information that hostip provides?

Comment: Yes I have included that second block of script that utilizes Google Maps API to fetch latitude-longitude.

I've now added the following:
// default latitude & longitude if no match returned by hostip.info - Palo Alto Stanford University
  $default_latitude = 37.4419;
  $default_longitude = -122.1419;
and after every 
$value = 'N/A';
I've added :
$latitude = default_latitude;
$longitude = default_longitude;

to return a default value.

Do you see a map now ?

Answer (score 0):

According to this post http://www.techsirius.com/2014/07/visitor-realtime-geo-location-in-google-map.html it seems it is possible.

Basically it is fetching database record for country, state, and city based on given IP. It seems that database IP record is stored in IPlong format that is why it is possible to store that much IP record in one database.

After that all depended on Google Geocoding API and Google Maps JS v3 API.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&key=<?=$google_api_key?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 var option = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$lat?>, <?=$lng?>),
   zoom: 5
 };
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("visitor_map"), option);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$lat?>, <?=$lng?>),
    map: map
 });
});
</script>
```